# Smoothing the fading in of a div as I hover over another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Dear Stackoverflow readers,

Using jQuery, is there a way for me to smooth out the fading in of my `.moreBio` after hovering over `.biography`?

I have two problems with my code right now:

The first time I hover over the `.biography`, `.moreBio` instantly fades in when I want it to fade in to `opacity: 1` in `0.5s`.

The second time (and every other time afterwards), `.moreBio` instantly jumps from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1` really quick, showing no smooth transition from `0 to 1` in `0.5s`.

I can transition `.moreBio` using CSS, however, I want to hide `.moreBio` whenever I'm not hovering over `.biography`, and I figured that jQuery gives me that option.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="biography">
    <p id="playerInfoMsg">Hover For Player Info</p>
    <br>
    <p class="moreBio">Favorite Hero
        <br>
        <img src="http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/7/72/Terrorblade.png" width="256" height="144" alt="Favorite Hero">
        <br>Terrorblade
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.biography {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #3399FF;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
.biography:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 360px;
    height: 450px;
    opacity: 1;
    background: #7C7C7C;
}
.moreBio {
    opacity: 0;
}
.biography:hover .moreBio {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.moreBio').hide();
    $('.biography').hover(function(e) {
        $(this).find('#playerInfoMsg').html('Player Info');
        $('.moreBio').fadeIn(2000);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('#playerInfoMsg').html("Hover For Player Info");
        $('.moreBio').hide();
    });
});
```

And here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQJFr/2/).

Thanks in advance, if my question is unclear please tell me.

Comment: You won't need jQuery for that. That is possible with pure CSS transitions/animations. Also it's unclear and hard to understand which is divA and divB. Is divA your `.biography`? Please edit your questin with the correct classes so we can help you better.

Comment: You can normally do it by using the "+" in your css. You should look for the use of the operator in css.

Comment: I edited my question to the correct classes to make it clearer, sorry about that.

Comment: I edited the post to make it clearer, I believe my comment confused you.  Let me try to reiterate, I'm using jQuery because I want to hide my `.moreBio` when I'm not hovering over `.biography`.  However, since I'm using jQuery (and a beginner at it), I can't make it smoothly transition hence my post above.

Comment: like hiding out slowly?

Comment: And fading in slowly, right now `.moreBio` doesn't do either smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQJFr/11/).
I added the same kind of animation than for your .moreBio but with the oposite opacity.
When you hover the `#playerInfoMsg` the div fade to a 0 opacity.

```
.biography {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #3399FF;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
.biography:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 360px;
    height: 450px;
    opacity: 1;
    background: #7C7C7C;
}
.moreBio {
    opacity: 0;
}
.biography #playerInfoMsg
{
    opacity : 1;
}
.biography:hover #playerInfoMsg
{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}
.biography:hover .moreBio {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}
```